# Problem using sed substitution command inside -exec option of find

Tags: bash, sed, find

Input 1:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'sed -n '1p' <(echo $1)' h {} \;
```

Output 1:

```
./file with space
```

Input 2:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'sed "1s_ _._" <(echo $1)' h {} \;
```

Output 2:

```
./file.with.space
```

Input 3:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'sed '1s_ _o_' <(echo $1)' h {} \;
```

Output 3:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

Why is the Output 3 an error? how does the single and double quote make a difference in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the parsing performed by the outer shell, the third command consists of the words `find`, `.`, `-maxdepth`, `1`, `-name`, `* *`, `-exec`, `bash`, `-c`, `sed 1s_`, `_o_ <(echo $1)`, `h`, `{}`, `;`. The word `sed 1s_` is a single argument since the space is within a single-quoted literal, and likewise for the next argument. Thus, when `find` reaches `./file with space`, it runs `bash` with the arguments `-c`, `sed 1s_`, `_o_ <(echo $1)`, `h`, `./file with space`. The shell script `sed 1s_` is the command `sed` with the argument `1s_`, and this is not a well-formed sed script.

You attempted to put a single-quoted string inside a single-quoted string, but that isn't possible: the second single quote ends the single-quoted string. You could use `'\''` to end the single-quoted literal, then put a literal single quote, and start a single-quoted literal again:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'sed '\''1s_ _o_'\'' <(echo $1)' h {} \;
```

Of course `<(echo $1)` breaks on file names containing wildcard characters or whitespace sequences other than a single space. I have no idea why you wrote that instead of `<<<"$1"`.

Comment: Thanks for having the patience and explaining this way. Learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because you are closing the single quote used for the bash command *-c* option.

So, you are running: `bash`, with first argument `-c`, second argument `sed 1s_`, third argument `_o_ <(echo $1)` and so on. Something like the following:

```bash
$ bash -c 'sed 1s_' '_o_ <(echo $1)'
```

The third argument (`'_o_ <(echo $1)'`) is passed to `bash`, not to `sed`.

To fix your command, you should use double quotes for the `sed` argument:

```bash
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'sed "1s_ _o_" <(echo $1)' h {} \;
```

Comment: How did
    
    $ bash -c 'sed '1s_ _o_' <(echo $1)'
    
became
    
    $ bash -c 'sed 1s_' '_o_' <(echo $1)
    
as you mentioned.

Comment: @boobalangnanasekaran You can't nest single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Reading it more carefully, the third argument is `_o_ <(echo $1)`. Fixed in the answer.